# Trying to build static CGO executable with oracle libraries on Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: oracle, go, static-linking, cgo, oci8

I have already searched for some days, tried several suggestions but none helped. At the moment I just want to create a small Go snippet which connects to an Oracle Database. While everything works by using normal `go build` and invoking the resulting dynamic linked application, I am stuck when I try to run the static compiler. I already have build other projects statically (even with CGO) without problems, but here gcc is not finding the oracle library. Maybe someone has a hint?

Error during build:

```
host link: "gcc" "-m64" "-gdwarf-2" "-o" "/tmp/go-build319417544/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/a.out" "-static" "/tmp/go-link-116023228/000000.o" "/tmp/go-link-116023228/000001.o" "/tmp/go-link-116023228/000002.o" "/tmp/go-link-116023228/go.o" "-g" "-O2" "-g" "-O2" "-lpthread" "-g" "-O2" "-L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib" "-lclntsh" "-static"
/home/hannes/.gvm/gos/go1.5/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Build command

```
 CGO_ENABLED=1  go build -work -x -ldflags  " -v -linkmode external -extldflags -static"  ${MAIN_SRC}
```

Application code:

```
package main
/*
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/include
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib -lclntsh
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-oci8"
    "time"
)

func main(){


    db, err := sql.Open("oci8", "...")
    ...
}
```

I have checked with

```
dconfig -p | grep cln
libkadm5clnt_mit.so.9 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkadm5clnt_mit.so.9
libclntshcore.so.12.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1
libclntshcore.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so
libclntsh.so.12.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
libclntsh.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so
```

The dynamic build executable (just "go build oracle_test.go) has everything it needs:

```
ldd oracle_test 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffeac867000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f083ef82000)
libclntsh.so.12.1 => /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 (0x00007f083bfc5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f083bbfa000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005615b32e8000)
libmql1.so => /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libmql1.so (0x00007f083b984000)
libipc1.so => /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libipc1.so (0x00007f083b606000)
libnnz12.so => /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libnnz12.so (0x00007f083aefb000)
libons.so => /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libons.so (0x00007f083acb6000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f083aab2000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f083a7a9000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f083a58f000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f083a387000)
libaio.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1 (0x00007f083a184000)
libclntshcore.so.12.1 => /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1 (0x00007f0839c12000)
```

I also tried to put/export CGO_LDFLAGS and/ord LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, which didn't help.

Pkg-config shows as well the library

```
pkg-config --libs oci8
-L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib -lclntsh
```

After looking for the static libraries, I have installed the complete oracle database package and now I have some more files in lib folder: 
`ls  /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/lib*.a

-rw-r--r--  1   1424782 /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libagent12.a
-rw-r--r--  1   1962088 /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libasmclnt12.a
-rw-r--r--  1   2187864 /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libasmclntsh12.a
-rw-r--r--  1   11386   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libasmperl12.a
-rw-r--r--  1   28454   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libavstub12.a
-rw-r--r--  1   7408322 /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libcell12.a
-rw-r--r--  1   11246008    /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclient12.a
-rw-r--r--  1   0   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntst12.a
-rw-r--r--  1   1749282 /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclsr12.a
-rw-r--r--  1   10087032    /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libcommon12.a
-rw-r--r--  1   5803698 /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libcore12.a
-rw-r--r--  1   6051402 /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libctx12.a
-rw-r--r--  1   1201840 /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libctxc12.a
-rw-r--r--  1   56964   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libctxs12.a
...snipped...`

As seen the one file has zero size, so I had to run $ORACLE_HOME/bin/genclntst to generate libclntst12.a.

Comment: You haven't shown if `/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/` contains static libs for everything you need (or if the system has static versions of its dependencies, but that's more likely)

Comment: Hi, I have to admit that I have not to much knowledge when it comes to compiling static programs. So, here is my directory: 
`ls /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/
glogin.sql             
libclntsh.so           
libclntsh.so.12.1  
libclntshcore.so       
libclntshcore.so.12.1  
libipc1.so         
libmql1.so         
libnnz12.so        
libocci.so       
libocci.so.12.1  
libociei.so     
libocijdbc12.so  
libons.so         
liboramysql12.so  
libsqlplus.so     
libsqlplusic.so   
ojdbc6.jar
ojdbc7.jar
ottclasses.zip
xstreams.jar
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use $ORACLE_HOME/bin/relink tool to generate the library named `libclntst.a`
  The `st` stands for static library. Oracle client is not usually shipped with this file. The
- Try to link your app with this library. You will most probably find many symbols missing.
- Use nm tool to find the source of those missing symbols.
- In case of 11gR2 this command worked for me:

  ```
  /usr/bin/c++ -Wall -ggdb3 -fPIC \
   CMakeFiles/opassgen.dir/opassgen.cpp.o \
   CMakeFiles/opassgen.dir/dbutils.cpp.o \
   CMakeFiles/opassgen.dir/common.cpp.o  \
   CMakeFiles/opassgen.dir/crypto.cpp.o  \
   n.o  -o opassgen                      \
   -rdynamic -static-libgcc -L. -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -Wl,-Bdynamic \
   /home/oracle/ivan/openssl-1.0.1t/libcrypto.a  \
   /oracle/u01/db/11.2.0.4/lib/libclntst11.a     \
   /oracle/u01/db/11.2.0.4/lib/libippdcmerged.a  \
   /oracle/u01/db/11.2.0.4/lib/libippsmerged.a   \
   -Wl,--whole-archive libtrotl.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive \
   -lpthread -ldl
  ```

Static linking requires, that you resolve all the dependencies manually.
In this example libclntst11.a depends on symbols from libippdcmerged.a and libippsmerged.a.

On older Oracle version the whole database was build and linked using Intel's ICC compiler. So when linking Oracle's client lib statically you also had to add some static libs from ICC's runtime.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer. I don't have the relink tool in my installation (I don't have the oracle full install), I downloaded some of the instant client packages and installed them on ubuntu via alien (followed instructions from here: [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client]) . Will check later if relink is inside some other package I didn't unzip/install yet.

Comment: Hi, so I found out that (see above comment) I am missing the ".a" static libraries. My folder contains only the shared files. Now I am chasing the $ORACLE_HOME/bin/relink as it is not available via the installation procedure I followed from the Ubuntu community. I hope the tool will then generate the ".a" files

Comment: Hi, meanwhile I have installed the oracle installation and found the relink tool. In the logs of the tool I find some error messages regarding the linker (again), so I have to go through them to fix them until I get the static library....I guess...

Comment: Hi, I made it to run the relink tool after fixing some issues (mainly with the help of (https://gemsofprogramming.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/installing-oracle-12c-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit-a-hard-journey-but-its-worth-it/). You are right, now I have tons of symbols missing and need to resolve them.