# Build static binary with cgo, LuaJIT and musl

Tags: go, luajit, musl

After reading [*Statically compiled Go programs, always, even with cgo, using musl*](https://dominik.honnef.co/posts/2015/06/go-musl/) I'm trying to use described method to statically link [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/).

- Using https://github.com/aarzilli/golua go bindings
- Assuming [musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/) and [golua](https://github.com/aarzilli/golua) are already installed

Go code I try to build:

```
package main

import "github.com/aarzilli/golua/lua"
import "fmt"

func test(L *lua.State) int {
    fmt.Println("hello world! from go!")
    return 0
}

func test2(L *lua.State) int {
    arg := L.CheckInteger(-1)
    argfrombottom := L.CheckInteger(1)
    fmt.Print("test2 arg: ")
    fmt.Println(arg)
    fmt.Print("from bottom: ")
    fmt.Println(argfrombottom)
    return 0
}

func main() {
    L := lua.NewState()
    defer L.Close()
    L.OpenLibs()

    L.GetField(lua.LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "print")
    L.PushString("Hello World!")
    L.Call(1, 0)

    L.PushGoFunction(test)
    L.PushGoFunction(test)
    L.PushGoFunction(test)
    L.PushGoFunction(test)

    L.PushGoFunction(test2)
    L.PushInteger(42)
    L.Call(1, 0)

    L.Call(0, 0)
    L.Call(0, 0)
    L.Call(0, 0)

    // this will fail as we didn't register test2 function
    err := L.DoString("test2(42)")

    fmt.Printf("Ciao %v\n", err)
}
```

Build command with parameters and output:

```
$ CC="/usr/local/musl/bin/musl-gcc" go build --ldflags '-linkmode external -extldflags "-static"' basic.go
# command-line-arguments
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running /usr/local/musl/bin/musl-gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lluajit-5.1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Using `LD_DEBUG=all` I can get [more information](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/776297075dcc080a20ffe435902f3f57) (8000+ lines).

My question: **what is the problem and how to solve it**? I think there can be some hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785691/trying-to-build-static-cgo-executable-with-oracle-libraries-on-linux-ubuntu) but I can't quite grasp it.

I took following steps:

### 1. Build static LuaJIT library with musl.

```
$ make STATIC_CC="/usr/local/musl/bin/musl-gcc" CCOPT="-static -fPIC" BUILDMODE="static"
...
==== Successfully built LuaJIT 2.0.4 ====
```

### 2. Build dynamic LuaJIT library with musl.

```
$ make DYNAMIC_CC="/usr/local/musl/bin/musl-gcc" BUILDMODE="dynamic"
...
==== Successfully built LuaJIT 2.0.4 ====
```

### 3. Check build.

```
$ find . -iname *.a -o -iname *.so
./src/libluajit.a
./src/libluajit.so
```

### 4. Install it.

```
$ sudo make install
...
==== Successfully installed LuaJIT 2.0.4 to /usr/local ====
```

### 5. Check installation.

```
$ pkg-config luajit --cflags
-I/usr/include/luajit-2.0
$ pkg-config luajit --libs
-lluajit-5.1
```

### 6. Modify golua `lua.go` file to use hardcoded `cgo` parameters.

I had problems overriding those values so I simply modify source code.

old `C` comment with `cgo` parameters:

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I ${SRCDIR}/lua
#cgo llua LDFLAGS: -llua
#cgo luaa LDFLAGS: -llua -lm -ldl
#cgo linux,!llua,!luaa LDFLAGS: -llua5.1
#cgo darwin,!luaa pkg-config: lua5.1
#cgo freebsd,!luaa LDFLAGS: -llua-5.1
#cgo windows,!llua LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR} -llua -lmingwex -lmingw32
#include <lua.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "golua.h"
*/
import "C"
```

new:

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/include/luajit-2.0 -I${SRCDIR}/lua
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lluajit-5.1
#include <lua.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "golua.h"
*/
import "C"
```

### 7. Build some example

As shown at the beggining of question.

#### Where LuaJIT got installed:

```
$ find / -iname libluajit* 2> /dev/null
/usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.so.2
/usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.a
/usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.so
/usr/local/lib/libluajit-5.1.so.2.0.4
/usr/lib/libluajit-5.1.so.2.0.5
/usr/lib/libluajit-5.1.so.2
/usr/lib/libluajit-5.1.a
/usr/lib/libluajit-5.1.so
/usr/lib/libluajit.s
```

---

### EDIT 1

I've followed [@putu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6207052/) comment and changed `#cgo LDFLAGS` to

```
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib -lluajit-5.1
```

now I have

```
$ CC="/usr/local/musl/bin/musl-gcc" go build --ldflags '-linkmode external -extldflags "-static -fPIC"' basic.go
# command-line-arguments
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running /usr/local/musl/bin/musl-gcc failed: exit status 1
/tmp/go-link-916770907/000000.o: In function `printf':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:104: undefined reference to `__printf_chk'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: How if you change the `LDFLAGS` to `#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib -lluajit-5.1`?

Comment: @putu Edited my question to show result after this modification. Thank you for comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@putu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6207052/) pointed me to the right direction, all I had to do was tune `CFLAGS` to include `musl`.

Cleaned up `C` comment in `lua.go`:

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/include/luajit-2.0 -I/usr/local/musl/include/
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib -lluajit-5.1
#include <lua.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "golua.h"
*/
import "C"
```

Looks like everything builds just fine:

```
$ CC="/usr/local/musl/bin/musl-gcc" go build --ldflags '-linkmode external -extldflags "-static"' basic.go
$ file basic
basic: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
$ ./basic 
Hello World!
test2 arg: 42
from bottom: 42
hello world! from go!
hello world! from go!
hello world! from go!
Ciao [string "test2(42)"]:1: attempt to call global 'test2' (a nil value)
```